# I am Wondering if this useEffect Actually Only Runs When the useMemo has Nothing in it

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios, react-usememo

So, I am wondering if this makes sense at all. I am trying to cache the data/users when the data is fetched with Axios, but make this useEffect run only when cachedUsers.length has no length. Does this have any propose or is there a better way to do this?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const GetAllUsers = () => {
  const [fsUsers, setFsUsers] = useState([]);
  const [notFoundErr, setNotFoundErr] = useState("");
  const [loading, toggleLoading] = useState(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const cachedUsers = useMemo(() => fsUsers, [fsUsers]);

  // Gets all users in Firestore DB.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        toggleLoading(true);
        const res = await axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:4000/auth/api/firebase/users",
          validateStatus: (status) => {
            return status === 200 || status === 404;
          },
        });
        console.log(res.data);
        if (res && res.status === 200) {
          setFsUsers(res.data);
        } else if (res && res.status === 404) {
          setNotFoundErr("No users found.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        navigate("/error500");
      } finally {
        toggleLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, [!cachedUsers.length]);

  return [cachedUsers, notFoundErr, loading];
};

export default GetAllUsers;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I was trying to aim for. Cache the user (for profile page) when the user visits that page for the first time. Then when the user navigates to that page again, it doesn't have to send that request to the server and not waste time and resources.

```
// CacheContext.js
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const CacheContext = createContext();

export const CacheProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cache, setCache] = useState({ userProfile: null });

  return (
    <CacheContext.Provider value={{ cache, setCache }}>
      {children}
    </CacheContext.Provider>
  );
};

// useCache.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CacheContext } from "../contexts/cache";

const useCache = () => {
  return useContext(CacheContext);
};

export default useCache;

// GetUser.js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import useCache from "../../../hooks/useCache";

const GetUser = (id) => {
  const [notFoundErr, setNotFoundErr] = useState("");
  const { cache, setCache } = useCache();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Gets stored user.
  useEffect(() => {
    let abortController;

    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      try {
        if (cache.userProfile === null) {
          abortController = new AbortController();
          setNotFoundErr("");
          const res = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `http://localhost:4000/auth/api/firebase/users/${id}`,
            signal: abortController.signal,
            validateStatus: (status) => {
              return status === 200 || status === 404;
            },
          });
          // console.log(res.data);

          if (res && res.status === 200) {
            setCache((prev) => ({ ...prev, userProfile: res.data }));
          } else if (res && res.status === 404) {
            setNotFoundErr(res.data.user);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === "ECONNABORTED" || error.message === "canceled") {
          console.warn("Request was aborted.");
        } else {
          console.error(error);
          navigate("/error500");
        }
      }
    };
    fetchDetails();

    return () => {
      if (abortController) abortController.abort();
    };
  }, []);

  return [cache.userProfile, notFoundErr];
};

export default GetUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useMemo` in your code has no effect since you're just returning the value in state (you can use that directly). `useMemo` will re-evaluate every time `fsUsers` updates so unless you were transforming/normalizing that data there's no point to memoize.

In terms of the `useEffect` if I understand correctly, you want to make this request once, so you can just use an empty dependency array to make the api call whenever the hook mounts:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const GetAllUsers = () => {
  const [fsUsers, setFsUsers] = useState([]);
  const [notFoundErr, setNotFoundErr] = useState("");
  const [loading, toggleLoading] = useState(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Gets all users in Firestore DB.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        toggleLoading(true);
        const res = await axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:4000/auth/api/firebase/users",
          validateStatus: (status) => {
            return status === 200 || status === 404;
          },
        });
        console.log(res.data);
        if (res && res.status === 200) {
          setFsUsers(res.data);
        } else if (res && res.status === 404) {
          setNotFoundErr("No users found.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        navigate("/error500");
      } finally {
        toggleLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  return [cachedUsers: fsUsers, notFoundErr, loading];
};

export default GetAllUsers;
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to keep the users in memory somehow even if the component re-renders, when it re-renders the useEffect goes off again and fetches the user, which I don't want. I don't want to fetch the user if we already did. So, I am going to try to use session storage to store the user if we already did, but I don't like using local storage...

Comment: Assuming you mean you want to persist the data across component mounts (since the solution I posted will persist the data across renders).  I think your best bet in that case is redux or a client side caching tool like [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/)

Answer (score 0):

`!cachedUsers.length` is `true` if and only if `cachedUsers.length == 0`.

Including `!cachedUsers.length` in the [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect) dependency array will trigger the hook to run whenever `!cachedUsers.length` changes,
 this only happens when `!cachedUsers.length` goes from `true` to `false` or the other way around.
In other words when `cachedUsers.length` goes from `0` to `n` or the other way around..

So this useEffect runs :

1. on mount (this will happen anyway) so if that's enough and you want your useEffect to fire only once, after the component is mounted, then give it an empty dependency array `[]` as second parameter.
2. when cachedUsers become an empty array (but not if it was already an empty array).
3. also when the cachedUsers is no longer an empty array: for example after the first mount, useEffect runs and updates `fsUsers` which will trigger useMemo in the next render and this latter will trigger useEffect because `cachedUsers` is no longer empty array).

   to avoid this, you can add a condition inside the useEffect callback function:

   ```js
   if (cachedUsers.length === 0) {
   //...
   }
   ```

   this won't prevent useEffect from running but at least the code inside it won't be executed if `cachedUsers` is not empty, in other words when `cachedUsers.length` goes from `0` to `n` since you don't care about this case

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-scooby-p03nwi?file=/src/App.js) **without strict mode**, have a look, and try comment/uncomment the commented code

keep in mind that:

```js
setFsUsers(res.data); // res.data may be an empty array
```

---

As it is mentioned in @DannyMoshe answer the [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) hook in your example is useless, its value changes each time `fsUsers` is updated so it is nothing but a copy of it.
get rid of it and use `fsUsers` instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did try the if (cachedUsers.length === 0), but I figured out that useMemo, on every time the component re-renders, the memo goes to an empty array and then it notices that nothing changed and then the memo returns the same result again. So for that moment that the memo is empty, the useEffect fires, so it all didn't matter. WHAT I AM TRYING TO achieve is to keep the users in memory somehow even if the component re-renders, when it re-renders the useEffect goes off again and fetches the user, which I don't want. I don't want to fetch the user if we already did.

Comment: So, I am going to try to use session storage to store the user if we already did, but I don't like using local storage...

Comment: I have added a sandbox to examplain what's going on, check it and see the logs